# The correct excel formula to be used for this function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What Excel function do I use if I want to give a 3% commission to consecutive sales of over 5000. The person sold tickets every week for four weeks, a 3% commision is to be given if the person made 5000 each week for  two consecutive weeks.

Comment: You need to show some effort first - what have you tried, and on what data?

Comment: At least show your data sample. Approach may differ depending on your data structure. So even if I have something in mind, I can't share it because the will be too many possible functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(AND(A1>5000,B1>5000),C1*1.03)
```

Replacing A1 and B1 with the weekly sales, C1 is the amount the commission is to be paid on